# How to deal with namespaces in Eloquent relations in L5?

Tags: php, laravel-5

So I have folder `app/Models/Blog` in which are two files: `Posts.php` and `Tags.php`. This two files are in same `App\Models\Blog` namespace, but to use Many to Many relation I need call like `$this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Blog\Tags');` otherwise I get an exception that Tags class not found... Is it possible to somehow get rid of `App\Models\Blog\` namespace and call just `Tags`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do it but I think it's a bad idea.  You can add aliases for your classes in app/Config/app.php so that you alias App\Models\Blog\Tags to Tags just like the laravel classes are aliased.

I think this is a bad idea because it pollutes the root namespace.  You will eventually have class naming conflicts because you're trying to alias App\Models\Blog\Tags and AnotherApp\Models\PaymentGateway\Tags to the same alias, for example.  This is the problem that namespacing was designed to solve, but aliasing classes to the root namespace makes the problem re-appear.